# Error uploading .pfx certificate to Azure Web app using ARM template from VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I'm using a Azure Resource Manager(ARM) template to create and update a resource group in a release definition in Visual Studio Team Services(VSTS). I'm using the same template to upload the .pfx certificate to the web app.

For the first deployment the certificate got uploaded perfectly, but from the next deployment the deployment fails with the error **"Another certificate exists with same thumbprint ******** at location West US in the Resource Group MyResourceGroup".**

I tried recreating the webapp, but to my surprise the deployment fails for the first time itself. Looks like the certificate got uploaded to the resource group.

Is there a way to overwrite the existing .pfx certificate for every deployment.

Comment: This is a very valid problem. Creating other resources via ARM template is idempotent. Why isn't uploading a certificate the same?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to upload certificate for all deployments. The first certificate will become available to all deployments

Comment: Correct. Why would you want to re-upload the cert when it is already present in the resource. Only if you delete the resource group at the end of a CI pipeline would you need to upload the cert again, but as part of creating the entire environment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The certificate is getting uploaded for every website that is created in that resource group. This is not something I wanted. Is there a way to delete that certificate from the resource group and to add it to a particular website, rather than adding it to the resource group.

Comment: Actually, the resource group has nothing to do with the certificate that you are uploading as it is a logical grouping of resources . The certificate that you're uploading will be available to all the apps which are in the same App Service Plan as the certificate is loaded into the certificate store.

Comment: I'm trying to automate the certificate upload process through release definition. is there a way to check if the certificate is present or not, if present then the upload step would be ignored.

Comment: @SarathRachuri did you ever solve this problem? like all over resources you want them to be idempotent / incremental.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are exposed at the resource group level, so deploying the same certificate again will definitely error out.

However, I don't see a reason as to why you need to upload a certificate. 
Does your application need to read this certificate? if yes, then there is a different way to do this. See this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Comment: Yes, my application needs to read this certificate. The link you have provided uploads the certificate through portal or through the REST API. But here I'm trying to upload the certificate from release definition using ARM template.

Comment: @SarathRachuri I can feel your pain. If a Phoenix Server deployment pattern could be used, the problem wouldn't even exist. VSTS or ARM doesn't seem to support that in a good way yet.

Comment: I am trying to understand as to what is the necessity to upload the same certificate every time? or is it a different certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Until today I had never encountered this error. I have been able to redeploy my applications, certificates and all, with no issues. I believe in my case that someone had previously manually added the certificate using a different name, possibly through the portal, and then when my pipeline executed it attempted to add the certificate using a different name.

Certificates are child resources of Microsoft.Web under the resource group. There are likely a number of options for resolving but I am going to focus on removing the certificate using [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com).  (I bet that there is a Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell command to do this too.)

In resource explorer, locate the certificates node associated with your resource group using the left hand navigation pane. This will likely be in something like subscriptions -> {subscription name} -> resourceGroups -> {resource group name} -> providers -> Microsoft.Web -> certificates -> {certificate name}

Once located, select your certificate and then can use the Actions (POST, DELETE) tab in the right hand pane to delete the certificate. You should then be able to redeploy.